# How to build/install OpenCV in Anaconda 3 on Max OS-X?

Tags: python, macos, opencv, installation, anaconda

I've tried installing directly through `conda`.

```
conda install opencv
```

But through this

```
The following specifications were found to be in conflict:
 - alabaster (target=alabaster-0.7.7-py35_0.tar.bz2) -> python 2.6*|2.7*|3.3*|3.4*|3.5*
 - anaconda (target=anaconda-4.0.0-np110py35_0.tar.bz2) -> anaconda-client
 ...
```

This error goes over a hundred lines.

I've also tried making it from `cmake`, but I can't seem to set the Python interpreter and related fields to the ones in Anaconda 3.

I've referred quite a few related posts, but it still didn't solve my problem.

[Installing openCV in anaconda3 - Python.h: No such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36814673/installing-opencv-in-anaconda3-python-h-no-such-file-or-directory)

[How to install python opencv through Conda?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23119413/how-to-install-python-opencv-through-conda)

Note: `conda install opencv` worked fine in Anaconda 2, but I don't know why so many package conflicts arise in Anaconda 3.

Comment: I just had the same problem. I ended up reinstalling anacoda, removing the 'anaconda' package before I could install the `opencv` package. Apparently, to install opencv, conda needs to downgrade a lot of packages.

Comment: Yes, @sietschie, that's what I wanted to avoid. I did find a way to run Python2 and Python3 in parallel in the same Anaconda package (but in different environments). I'm currently resorting to Python2 for OpenCV and porting back to Python3 for the analysis. I thought it would be much better to have the whole thing in a single environment. It doesn't seem all that possible does it?

Answer (score 0):

`conda install -c https://conda.binstar.org/menpo opencv`

Its useful.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/27650299

Comment: Sorry, but it didn't work for me. I suppose you are using Anaconda-2 for Python 2.7 or setting up a separate env. I just tried it and it throws the same conflict list.

Answer (score 0):

It's the solution:

`conda install -c menpo opencv3=3.1.0`