# Couldn't recognize Python.h when running make

Tags: python, opencv, makefile, cmake, anaconda

**Summary**

For OpenCV environment, after CMake configuration, I tried `make`, but error occurred, saying `Python.h: No such file or directory`.

**Environment**

- ubuntu 18.04,
- anaconda3-5.3.1 on pyenv,
- python3.7,
- opencv(4.0.1) and opencv_contrib(4.0.1)

**What I've done**

First, I tried CMake configure with some options below.`$CONDA_HOME` is equal to `/home/qcmp/anaconda3`.

```
(cv) (anaconda3-5.3.1/envs/cv) (base) qcmp@qcmp-Alienware-Aurora-R8:~/opencv/build$ cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local -D OPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=~/opencv_contrib/modules -D PYTHON3_EXECUTABLE=$CONDA_HOME/envs/cv/bin/python -D PYTHON3_PACKAGES_PATH=$CONDA_HOME/envs/cv/lib/python3.7/site-packages -D BUILD_opencv_python2=OFF -D BUILD_opencv_python3=ON -D INSTALL_PYTHON_EXAMPLES=ON -D INSTALL_C_EXAMPLES=OFF  -D OPENCV_ENABLE_NONFREE=ON -D BUILD_EXAMPLES=ON -D ENABLE_PRECOMPILED_HEADERS=OFF -D BUILD_TESTS=OFF -D PYTHON3_LIBRARY=/home/qcmp/anaconda3/lib/libpython3.7m.so -D PYTHON3_INCLUDE_DIR=/home/qcmp/anaconda3/include/python3.7m -D WITH_CUBLAS=OFF -D OpenBLAS_FOUND=OFF ..
```

The output is [here](https://hackmd.io/@AQjKsDijQLKBgM5UhRTOqA/rkBnaxXFS). There are some warning like `Could not find OpenBLAS include`, but maybe it doesn't relate to `make` problem(?)

After that, when `make -j8`, error occurred like below:

```
/home/qcmp/opencv/modules/python/src2/cv2.cpp:9:10: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory
 #include <Python.h>
          ^~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
modules/python3/CMakeFiles/opencv_python3.dir/build.make:62: recipe for target 'modules/python3/CMakeFiles/opencv_python3.dir/__/src2/cv2.cpp.o' failed
make[2]: *** [modules/python3/CMakeFiles/opencv_python3.dir/__/src2/cv2.cpp.o] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:12152: recipe for target 'modules/python3/CMakeFiles/opencv_python3.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [modules/python3/CMakeFiles/opencv_python3.dir/all] Error 2
```

The error says Python.h cannot be found. According to [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36814673/installing-opencv-in-anaconda3-python-h-no-such-file-or-directory), when running `cmake`, I attached options for adding path like `-D PYTHON3_LIBRARY=/home/qcmp/anaconda3/lib/libpython3.7m.so -D PYTHON3_INCLUDE_DIR=/home/qcmp/anaconda3/include/python3.7m`. Actually there is indeed a Python.h file in `home/qcmp/anaconda3/include/python3.7m/Python.h`.

I already tried `sudo apt-get install python3.7-dev` and `sudo apt-get install python3-dev`, according to [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21530577/fatal-error-python-h-no-such-file-or-directory), but it did not resolve the issue.

What should I do to fix it?

**Edited**

I changed cmake options from setting file path to searching one.

```
cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=$(python -c "import sys; print(sys.prefix)")  -D OPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=~/opencv_contrib/modules -D PYTHON3_INCLUDE_DIR=$(python -c "from distutils.sysconfig import get_python_inc; print(get_python_inc())") -D PYTHON3_EXECUTABLE=$(which python) -D PYTHON3_PACKAGES_PATH=$(python -c "from distutils.sysconfig import get_python_lib; print(get_python_lib())") -D PYTHON3_LIBRARY=$(python -c "import distutils.sysconfig as sysconfig; print(sysconfig.get_config_var('LIBDIR') + '/' + sysconfig.get_config_var('LDLIBRARY'))") -D BUILD_opencv_python2=OFF -D BUILD_opencv_python3=ON -D INSTALL_PYTHON_EXAMPLES=ON -D INSTALL_C_EXAMPLES=OFF  -D OPENCV_ENABLE_NONFREE=ON -D BUILD_EXAMPLES=ON ..
```

Searching reference is below.

```
$ which python
/home/qcmp/.pyenv/shims/python
$ python -c "from distutils.sysconfig import get_python_inc; print(get_python_inc())"
/home/qcmp/.pyenv/versions/anaconda3-5.3.1/envs/cv/include/python3.7m
$ python -c "from distutils.sysconfig import get_python_lib; print(get_python_lib())"
/home/qcmp/.pyenv/versions/anaconda3-5.3.1/envs/cv/lib/python3.7/site-packages
$ python -c "import sys; print(sys.prefix)"
/home/qcmp/.pyenv/versions/anaconda3-5.3.1/envs/cv
$ python -c "import distutils.sysconfig as sysconfig; print(sysconfig.get_config_var('LIBDIR') + '/' + sysconfig.get_config_var('LDLIBRARY'))"
/home/qcmp/.pyenv/versions/anaconda3-5.3.1/envs/cv/lib/libpython3.7m.so
```

However, I still get the same error.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow!! It looks like you may be providing two different Python locations in your options to `cmake`. You have this `$CONDA_HOME/envs/cv/bin/python` and this `/home/qcmp/anaconda3/lib`. Are these truly pointing to the same Python installation? If not, was this intentional?

Comment: I forgot to say that `$CONDA_HOME` is equal to `/home/qcmp/anaconda3`. Also, I  confused at Python location. I agree instead of  `/home/qcmp/anaconda3/lib`, `/home/qcmp/anaconda3/envs/cv/lib`or  `$CONDA_HOME/envs/cv/lib` is correct. However, this cannot fix the error.

Comment: [Edited] `$CONDA_HOME` is not equal to `/home/qcmp/anaconda3`, but `/home/qcmp/.pyenv/versions/anaconda3-5.3.1`.